# Add image dimention after product image name in bulk

Tags: database, image, magento, product

I have an  E-commerce  website and have multiple products and images.

I want to add dimensions after every product images which have already uploaded.

Ex: **product_name_1024x1024**

Is there any way or I have  to rename images 1 by 1.

Comment: Do you need to just rename the files, or Magento's image paths as well?

Comment: I just want to rename image name only.

Comment: Be careful of what names you used. I found that some brwoser extensions, such as add blockers, will block some images if their names include typical banner ad sizes (I think 200x200 was one). I no longer use image sizes for that reason.

Comment: Thanks @PedroKTFC.. but as I see, even google also use Dimensions after every image file name and also it is good for SEO prospectus.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommended installing Netzarbeiter_NicerImageNames; https://github.com/Vinai/nicer-image-names

With this extension, you can define a mask for the image file names being shown on the frontend. Unfortuantely, it does not have a %width or %height attribute by default so you'll need to modify the extension.

I've taken a quick look and can point you in the right direction; add the filename variable as an argument to _getGeneratedNameForImageAttribute() so it will be _getGeneratedNameForImageAttribute($attributeName, $map = null, $forFiles = true, $fileName = null). Use getimagesize() to find width and height attribute when $fileName is not null and map 'width' and 'height' to these variables (see requestHost for example). Then look for every place in the code where _getGeneratedNameForImageAttribute() is called and add in the filename variable used within that function.

Finally, add the %height and %width variables to your map in the configuration under Catalog.

Comment: Sorry Peter, But m not looking for that. I want to add image dimensions with image name.

Comment: Yes that is what I was referring to.